# React native crop image (with drag em drop) - just like instagram profile picture editor

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I need assistance with a design proposal. I'd like to know if there's a way to create a "Drag and Drop" image cropper, similar to the one in the Instagram profile picture editor. Any insights on how I can achieve this? Currently, I'm using the react-native-image-crop-picker library, but it doesn't allow me to create a view where the user can drag and drop the selected image to crop around a circle (like Instagram does).
I'm aware that achieving this is possible in React JS with react-easy-crop. However, I'm curious if anyone knows how to achieve the same functionality in React Native.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I would like to create a view that allows crop image (like react-easy-crop)